# Write a program to display directory treehouse

Tags: code-golf, string, file-system

Given a directory (such as `C:/`), given from stdin or read from a file, produce a directory tree, with each file/folder indented based on its depth.

#### Example

If I have a `C:/` drive which only contains two folders `foo` and `bar`, and `bar` is empty while `foo` contains `baz.txt`, then running with input `C:/` produces:

```
C:/
    bar/
    foo/
        baz.txt
```

while running with input `C:/foo/` should produce

```
foo/
    baz.txt
```

As this is codegolf, lowest byte count wins. The file extensions (such as `baz.txt`) are optional.
Extra notes: hidden files can be ignored, directories must actually exist, it can be assumed that files do not contain unprintable characters or new lines but all other printable ASCII characters are fine (file names with spaces must be supported). Output can be written to file or stdout. The indentations can be made up of either a tab character or 4 spaces.

Comment: Extra note: this question is poorly formatted, so a reformatting would be appreciated.

Comment: Are languages that do not have access to files automatically disqualified?

Comment: What filenames have to be supported? Files with spaces in their names? With newlines? With unprintable characters? What about hidden files (beginning with `.`)?

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan I believe the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Edits have been made.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/17948/48934).

Comment: @LeakyNun I'm aware of that question, but this is entirely different.

Comment: @Mathime What is the difference?

Comment: @LeakyNun Output of reference question is an array of arrays. This question requires a representation of the directory tree to be printed to stdout.

Comment: What characters specifically may the files contain? Only letters, numbers, and spaces? Or can there be a file called `{{}{#)((*[']238..23[]]4.2]3["'''"`?

Comment: directory entries sorted, unsorted or no preference?

Comment: @Doorknob any printable ascii characters

Comment: @Titus if you mean alphabetically sorted, no preference.

Comment: Must directories have trailing ``\``? It is obvious that they are dirs because of the indentation.

Comment: @Adám they are preferred but not mandatory.

Comment: Must the first output line of `C:/foo/` be `foo/` or is `C:/foo/` acceptable?

Comment: Can the input be a string parameter to a function?

Answer (score 10):

### bash, <s>61</s> <s>58</s> 54 bytes

```
find "$1" -exec ls -Fd {} \;|perl -pe's|.*?/(?!$)|  |g'
```

Takes input as a command line argument, outputs on STDOUT.

Note that the spaces near the end before the `|g` are actually a tab character (SE converts them to spaces when displaying posts).

```
find              crawl directory tree recursively
"$1"              starting at the input directory
-exec             and for each file found, execute...
ls -Fd {} \;      append a trailing slash if it's a directory (using -F of ls)
|perl -pe         pipe each line to perl
'
s|                replace...
.*?/              each parent directory in the file's path...
(?!$)             that doesn't occur at the end of the string...
|    |            with a tab character...
g                 globally
'
```

Thanks to [@Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) for 4 bytes!

Answer (score 2):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 48 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```
(⊂∘⊃,1↓'[^\\]+\\'⎕R'    ')r[⍋↑r←⎕SH'dir/s/b ',⍞]
```

`⍞` prompt for character input

`'dir/s/b ',` prepend text

`⎕SH` execute in shell

`r←` store in *r*

`↑` make list of strings into character matrix

`⍋` indices for ascending sorting

`r[`...`]` reorder *r* [sorted]

`(`...`)` on the standard out of the shell command, do:

`'[^\\]+\\'⎕R'    '` regex replace backslash-terminated runs of non-backslashes by four spaces

`1↓` drop the first line

`⊂∘⊃,` prepend the enclosed first [line]

Result of inputting "\tmp" to the prompt begins as follows on my computer:

```
C:\tmp\12u64
            keyboards64.msi
            netfx64.exe
            setup.exe
            setup_64_unicode.msi
            setup_dotnet_64.msi
        AdamsReg.reg
        AdamsReg.zip
        qa.dws
        ride-experimental
            win32
                d3dcompiler_47.dll
                icudtl.dat
                libEGL.dll
```

⋮

Comment: Aren't the directories supposed to have trailing \ characters?

Comment: @Neil *[they are preferred but not mandatory](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85531/write-a-program-to-display-directory-treehouse?noredirect=1#comment210259_85531)*

Answer (score 2):

### [SML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML), 176 bytes

```
open OS.FileSys;val! =chDir;fun&n w=(print("\n"^w^n);!n;print"/";c(openDir(getDir()))(w^"\t");!"..")and c$w=case readDir$of SOME i=>(&i w handle _=>();c$w)|x=>()fun%p=(&p"";!p)
```

Declares (amongst others) a function `%` which takes a string as argument. Call with `% "C:/Some/Path";` or `% (getDir());` for the current directory.

I'm using the normally rather functionally used language StandardML whose `FileSys`-Library I discovered after reading this challenge.

The special characters `!`, `&`, `$` and `%` have no special meaning in the language itself and are simply used as identifiers; however they can't be mixed with the standard alphanumeric identifiers which allows to get rid of quite some otherwise needed spaces.

```
open OS.FileSys;
val ! = chDir;                       define ! as short cut for chDir

fun & n w = (                        & is the function name
                                     n is the current file or directory name
                                     w is a string containing the tabs
    print ("\n"^w^n);                ^ concatenates strings
    ! n;                             change in the directory, this throws an 
                                     exception if n is a file name
    print "/";                       if we are here, n is a directory so print a /
    c (openDir(getDir())) (w^"\t");  call c with new directory and add a tab to w
                                     to print the contents of the directory n
    ! ".."                           we're finished with n so go up again
)
and c $ w =                          'and' instead of 'fun' must be used 
                                     because '&' and 'c' are mutual recursive
                                     $ is a stream of the directory content
    case readDir $ of                case distinction whether any files are left
        SOME i => (                  yes, i is the file or directory name
            & i w handle _ => ();    call & to print i an check whether it's a 
                                     directory or not, handle the thrown exception 
            c $ w )                  recursively call c to check for more files in $
        | x    => ()                 no more files, we are finished

fun % p = (                          % is the function name, 
                                     p is a string containing the path
    & p "";                          call & to print the directory specified by p
                                     and recursively it's sub-directories
    ! p                              change back to path p due to the ! ".." in &
)
```

Can be compiled like this with [SML/NJ](http://smlnj.org/) or with Moscow ML* by prefixing with `load"OS";`.

*See `mosml.org`, can't post more than 2 links.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 222 bytes

```cs
namespace System.IO{class P{static int n;static void Main(String[]a){Console.WriteLine(new string('\t',n++)+Path.GetFileName(a[0]));try{foreach(var f in Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(a[0])){a[0]=f;Main(a);}}catch{}n--;}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7LasMwEEV/RbtIOHa6N131RSFtA1l0kWYxTMf1gDMK0uDECH@7qibp6nLhPg7GGn2gnAUOFI@AZLZTVDo0rx8JB4jRbFJUUEbDokbamxk9f5s3YLFbDSw/uz249OAl@oGaz8BKaxayQicTLwG7@NLFUqrKVRvQvnkhfeaB3suvhd3d3rlWw5S6QgPY2xGC6cqleeRAqD5M/40r35OUVYq3avqT@669AIFr5xlBsU@z1HUxc855RYorpfPAI/0C)

---

The ungolf:

```cs
using System.IO;
using System;

class P
{
    static int n=0;
    static void Main(String[] a)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++) Console.Write("\t");
        Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(a[0]));
        n++;

        if(Directory.Exists(a[0]))
            foreach (String f in Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(a[0]))
                Main(new String[]{f});
        n--;
    }
}
```

First time I ever recursed a `Main` function!

I believe a person that has fresher knowledge of C# can golf it more, as I didn't program on C# for some time!

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 237 bytes

```
@echo off
echo %~1\
for /f %%d in ('dir/s/b %1')do call:f %1 %%~ad "%%d"
exit/b
:f
set f=%~3
call set f=%%f:~1=%%
set i=
:l
set i=\t%i%
set f=%f:*\=%
if not %f%==%f:*\=% goto l
set a=%2
if %a:~0,1%==d set f=%f%\
echo %i%%f%
```

Where \t represents the literal tab character. This version includes trailing `\`s on directories but 41 bytes can be saved if they are not needed.

Comment: the trailing `\\` s aren't needed

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 180 bytes

- first argument: path must have a trailing slash (or backslash)
- second argument: level defaults to `NULL` and will be interpreted as `0` by `str_repeat`; will throw a warning if not provided

```
function d($p,$e){$s=opendir($p);echo$b=str_repeat("\t",$e++),$e?basename($p)."/":$p,"
";while($f=readdir($s))echo preg_match("#^\.#",$f)?"":is_dir($p.$f)?d("$p$f/",$e):"$b\t$f
";}
```

- displays hidden files and directories, but does not recurse hidden directories
  add parentheses around `is_dir(...)?d(...):"..."` to remove hidden entries from output (+2)
  replace `"#^\.#"` with `#^\.+$#` to display/recurse hidden entries but skip dot entries (+2)
- may throw errors when directories are nested too deep. Insert `closedir($s);` before the final `}` to fix (+13)
- will fail if a directory contains an entry with no name, prepend `false!==` to the while condition to fix (+8)

**with glob, 182 bytes** (probably 163 in future php)

```
function g($p,$e){echo$b=str_repeat("\t",$e),$e++?basename($p)."/":$p,"
";foreach(glob(preg_replace("#[*?[]#","[$1]",$p)."*",2)as$f)echo is_dir($f)?g($f,$e):"$b\t".basename($f)."
";}
```

- does not display or recurse hidden files/directories
- `2` stands for `GLOB_MARK`, will append a slash to all directory names, as does `ls -F`
- the `preg_replace` escapes glob special characters
  I could have abused `preg_quote` for this (-19); but that would fail on Windows systems, as the backslash is the directory separator there.
- php *may* soon include a function [glob_quote](https://github.com/hholzgra/glob-quote), which will allow the same golfing as `preg_quote` and work on all systems.

**with iterators, 183 bytes**
(well, not purely iterators: I used implicit `SplFileInfo::__toString()` to golf `$f->getBaseName()` and `$f->isDir()` to the old PHP 4 functions.)

```
function i($p){echo"$p
";foreach($i=new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($p),1)as$f)echo str_repeat("\t",1+$i->getDepth()),basename($f),is_dir($f)?"/":"","
";}
```

- no trailing slash required
- displays and recurses hidden entries (`ls -a`)
- insert `,4096` or `,FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS` before `),1` to skip dot entries (+5) (`ls -A`)
- flag `1` stands for `RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST`

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell, 147 bytes

```
param($a)function z{param($n,$d)ls $n.fullname|%{$f=$_.mode[0]-ne"d";Write-Host(" "*$d*4)"$($_.name)$(("\")[$f])";If(!$f){z $_($d+1)}}}$a;z(gi $a)1
```

Man, I feel like PS should be able to do something like the bash answer, but I'm not coming up with anything shorter than what I've got here.

Explanation:

```
param($a)                     # assign first passed parameter to $a
function z{param($n,$d) ... } # declare function z with $n and $d as parameters
ls $n.fullname                # list out contents of directory
|%{ ... }                     # foreach
$f=$_.namde[0]-ne"d"          # if current item is a file, $f=true
Write-Host                    # writes output to the console
(" "*$d*4)                    # multiplies a space by the depth ($d) and 4
"$($_.name)$(("\")[$f])"      # item name + the trailing slash if it is a directory
;if(!$f){z $_($d+1)}          # if it is a directory, recursively call z
$a                            # write first directory to console
z(gi $a)1                     # call z with $a as a directoryinfo object and 1 as the starting depth
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 138 bytes

Modified from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9728478/2415524). Those are tabs for indentation, not spaces. Input will be taken like `"C:/"`.

```python
import os
p=input()
for r,d,f in os.walk(p):
    t=r.replace(p,'').count('/');print' '*t+os.path.basename(r)
    for i in f:print'   '*-~t+i
```

[**Try it online**](http://ideone.com/4P9uWR) - *It's pretty interesting that I'm allowed to browse the directory on Ideone...*

Same length:

```python
from os import*
p=input()
for r,d,f in walk(p):
    t=r.replace(p,'').count(sep);print' '*t+path.basename(r)
    for i in f:print'   '*-~t+i
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 116 bytes

```
proc L f {puts [string repe \t [expr [incr ::n]-1]][file ta $f];lmap c [glob -n -d $f *] {L $c};incr ::n -1}
L $argv
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NctBCoMwEAXQfU/xF64KQdzqFbxBmkU6TkIgjWGciiCePXXT7YOnlFurshJmBJz1qxvsppJKhHBlvBSWjyqwqZBgHIszg3M2pMxQjy64KX98BcHGvL5hCsxyM54O54yOruk/YYbrcZOXuLfWelbqlY@cdv4B)

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 89 bytes

It's useful when there's a find module in the core distribution. Perl's File::Find module does not traverse the tree in alphabetic order, but the spec didn't ask for that.

```
/usr/bin/perl -MFile::Find -nE 'chop;find{postprocess,sub{--$d},wanted,sub{say" "x$d.$_,-d$_&&++$d&&"/"}},$_'
```

The script proper is 76 bytes, I counted 13 bytes for the command-line options.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 205 bytes

```java
import java.io.*;public interface M{static void p(File f,String p){System.out.println(p+f.getName());if(!f.isFile())for(File c:f.listFiles())p(c,p+"\t");}static void main(String[]a){p(new File(a[0]),"");}}
```

This is a full program submission which takes input from its first command-line argument (not explicitly permitted, but done by many others) and prints output to standard out.

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##TY69csIwEIRfRXElBUdQx306aFwSF4o5kTOWdCOdYRiPn13I0FDut7M/g7mar0Dgh9MlZ3QUIouhQI1BfzY0/Y3YC/QM0ZoexN6gnxMbLvQa8CRI/uAIwtYtR/RnQWpu74nB6TCxpsJ49JI2Vp@BD8aBVKpBKz@sxrRGi7Yhvlr6b6tHTLyKVAySfU2b6pcr1Szvq67ckK/FY2fUTNLDTTzrzHHXqbpaE0vOefsfHGzj5D3EBw) (note different interface name)

### Ungolfed

```java
import java.io.*;

public interface M {
    static void p(File f, String p) {
        System.out.println(p + f.getName());
        if (!f.isFile())
            for (File c : f.listFiles())
                p(c, p + "\t");
    }

    static void main(String[] a) {
        p(new File(a[0]), "");
    }
}
```